# Miltiple domain/subdomain using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

My website has document root ~/public_html I'm trying to organize multi domain/subdomain redirection using htaccess.

Possible redirection logic: if domain/subdomain directory found - perform redirection, otherwise throw 404 Error.

Possible directory structure:

```
public_html/
            .htaccess (main redirect router)
public_html/
            domain-1/
                    application/
                    public_html/
                                .htaccess
public_html/
            domain-2/
                    application/
                    public_html/
                                .htaccess
public_html/
            domain-3/
                    application/
                    public_html/
                                .htaccess
public_html/
            subdomain-1.domain-1/
                                application/
                                public_html/
                                            .htaccess
public_html/
            subdomain-2.domain-1/
                                application/
                                public_html/
                                            .htaccess
```

---

Your help be deeply appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: That's what VirtualHosts are good for. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/vhosts/

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have access to apache settings according to my hoster restrictions.

Comment: Is it possible to solve my problem using htaccess only?

Comment: depends on your hoster. Do you have access to a tool where you can add new domains to your hosting package?

Comment: somehow apache has to map your domain(s) to your webspace. that's just in virtualhost afaik.

Comment: @wmk yes, I can add up to 50 domains, but also I have a restriction to have more than 2 site folders (sites).

Comment: I tryed to look at my problem from other side. How to avoid hoster restrictions on maximum amount of sites. 

Multisite issue can be easely  solved in application routing. So I attached a few domains to the same folder, and placed routing in main index.php, depending on requested $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']. Then I search for directory located in root and named for instance domain3.com or subdomain.domain2.com. If found - start application from there with specific configurations, otherwise start from default directory.

Comment: Also I removed robots.txt from root folder, and made it dynamic (route - controller). Very convinient. The issue is solved. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

your .htaccess file should have

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.domain.in [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.hardikvyas.in/$1 [L,R=301]

RedirectMatch ^/$ /redirection directory name/
```

Try this.

Comment: Thanks, Hardik Vyas! Another way to get it done:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.domain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/subdomain/$1 [L,NC,QSA]

Comment: Found other way, without .htaccess involved http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33277100/miltiple-domain-subdomain-using-htaccess?noredirect=1#comment54383405_33277100